# How to add router with query param to router list?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I want to add a route with query params.
If the url is `blog`, then navigate to index page.
If the url includes the `author` query param, replace a component on the page with the `BlogAuthorPage` component.

```js
router: {
  extendsRoutes(routes, resolve) {
    routes.push({
      name: 'author-page-detail',
      path: '/blog?author=*',
      component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/blog/author-page.vue')
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not be done in `nuxt.config.js`'s router key but rather in your `blog.vue` page directly with a [component router guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards).
The code below should be enough to check if the route does have a `author` query params and redirect to the `blog/author-page` page.

```html
<script>
export default {
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next((vm) => {
      if (vm.$route.query?.author) next({ name: 'blog-author-page' })
      else next()
    })
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't redirect toan another page, I  want to stay on a current page and substitute the main component of a page.

Comment: Then, you need to make the same kind of check inside of a `fetch()` or `asyncData()` hook and use a [dynamic component](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components). Can you share your `.vue` component?

Answer (score 1):

I use `"@nuxtjs/router": "^1.6.1",`

- nuxt.config.js

```js
  /*
  ** @nuxtjs/router module config
  */
  routerModule: {
    keepDefaultRouter: true,
    parsePages: true
  }
```

- router.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

import BlogIndexPage from '~/pages/blog/index'
import BlogAuthorPage from '~/pages/blog/author-page';

Vue.use(Router);

export function createRouter(ssrContext, createDefaultRouter, routerOptions, config) {
  const options = routerOptions ? routerOptions : createDefaultRouter(ssrContext, config).options

  return new Router({
    ...options,
    routes: [
      ...options.routes,
      {
        path: '/blog',
        component: ssrContext.req.url.includes('/blog?author') ? BlogAuthorPage : BlogIndexPage
      }
    ]
  })
}
```